# Symmetric function transition matrix and a non-conjecture by Clifford and Stanley

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions, integer-sequences, conjectures

Consider the transition matrix $R = \left(R_{\lambda,\mu}\right)$, defined by
$$
p_\lambda = \sum_{\mu} R_{\lambda\mu}m_\mu ,
$$
between the power-sum and the monomial basis of the ring of symmetric functions.
There are plenty of combinatorial descriptions of $R_{\lambda\mu}$,
it is for example the number of ordered brick-tableaux of shape $\lambda$ and brick-sizes determined by $\mu$, see e.g. [this excellent paper with transition matrices](https://doi.org/10.1016/0166-218X(91)90081-7) by Eğecioğlu and Remmel.

In [the paper on Bottom Schur functions](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v11i1r67/pdf) by P. Clifford and R. 
Stanley (2004), the authors consider the dimension of the null-space of
$R-D$, where $D$ is the diagonal of $R$.

As the size $n$ of the partitions increase, they computed (by computer I presume) the sequence of dimensions $d(n)$ is
$$
1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 7 , 9 , 11 , 15 , 19 , 24
$$
but they do not make any conjecture of what this sequence of integers might be.

However, a quick search in OEIS gives one result, [A129528](https://oeis.org/A129528),
entered in 2007, after Clifford and Stanley's paper was published.
The sequence A129528, $a(n)$ is defined as follows:
Consider the set of all Dyck paths, consisting of steps $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$. The peak-abscissa-sum of a path is the sum of the $x$-coordinates of all peaks. Then $a(n)$ is the number of Dyck paths of any length with peak-abscissa-sum $n$.

**Question:** Is there some neat way 
to show that A129528 is at least a lower bound of $d(n)$,
by explicitly constructing $a(n)$ linearly independent vectors in the null-space?

A good start is to examine the Bottom Schur functions defined in the paper, as they can be identified with elements in the null space of $R-D$.

Comment: Have you looked at the other eigenvalues of $RD^{-1}$ ? I wouldn't be surprised if they are integers, and their multiplicities count Dyck paths with other sums of peaks. (Sorry for backseat problemsolving -- I'm currently travelling and have a backlog of lecture notes to write.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg: I don't understand, $R$ is triangular, so $R-D$ has all eigenvalues equal to $0$, no?

Comment: Oh! You're right. Then I guess it's worth looking at the sizes of the Jordan blocks.

Comment: Here are the block sizes (the last being a partition of length 24): $[1]$,
$[2]$,
$[3]$,
$[4, 1]$,
$[5, 2]$,
$[6, 3, 2]$,
$[7, 4, 3, 1]$,
$[8, 5, 4, 3, 2]$,
$[9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]$,
$[10, 7, 6, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1]$,
$[11, 8, 7, 6, 6, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2]$,
$[12, 9, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]$,
$[13, 10, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]$,
$[14, 11, 10, 9, 9, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]$

Comment: It seems that, whenever there is only one Dyck path with given peak-abscissa-sum, then there is a vector with first non-zero coefficient indexed by the integer partition corresponding to the positions of the peaks.  For example, for $n=8$, the kernel is spanned by the vectors $(8)$, $(71)-(44)$, $(62)-(44)$, $(611)-2(521)+(332)$, $(53)-(44)$.  There are five Dyck paths with peak-abscissa-sum $8$, and the positions of the peaks are: $(8)$, $(71)$, $(62)$, $(62)$ and $(53)$.